# React - useCallback vs useMemo for JSX elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have implemented this component:

```
function CardList({
  data = [],
  isLoading = false,
  ListHeaderComponent,
  ListEmptyComponent,
  ...props
}) {
  const keyExtractor = useCallback(({ id }) => id, []);

  const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({ item, index }) => (
      <Card
        data={item}
        onLayout={(event) => {
          itemHeights.current[index] = event.nativeEvent.layout.height;
        }}
      />
    ),
    []
  );

  const renderFooter = useCallback(() => {
    if (!isLoading) return null;

    return (
      <View style={globalStyles.listFooter}>
        <Loading />
      </View>
    );
  }, [isLoading]);

  return (
    <FlatList
      {...props}
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      ListHeaderComponent={ListHeaderComponent}
      ListFooterComponent={renderFooter()}
      ListEmptyComponent={ListEmptyComponent}
    />
  );
}
```

As my CardList component is heavy, I have tried to optimize it following these [tips](https://codingislove.com/optimize-react-native-flatlist-performance/).

But, I think that instead of using `useCallback` for `renderFooter`, I should use `useMemo`, in order to memoize the resulted JSX and not the method:

```
const ListFooterComponent = useMemo(() => {
  if (!isLoading) return null;

  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.listFooter}>
      <Loading />
    </View>
  );
}, [isLoading]);
```

Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general `useMemo` is used to cache the result of a calculation between re-renders; seems that is more appropriate for your case because you are calling `renderFooter` and passing its result as props.

Note there is also a possibility to optimize rendering using `useMemo`, it is highlighted in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-memoize-calculations):

```
function Parent({ a, b }) {
  // Only re-rendered if `a` changes:
  const child1 = useMemo(() => <Child1 a={a} />, [a]);
  // Only re-rendered if `b` changes:
  const child2 = useMemo(() => <Child2 b={b} />, [b]);
  return (
    <>
      {child1}
      {child2}
    </>
  )
}
```

The reason why it works here is probably due to the fact that when during a re-render, react *sees reference to the same react element in the same place in component hierarchy*, it skips re-rendering it. This happens here because by using `useMemo` to create `child1` and `child2` elements, we ensure that the same element reference is returned on subsequent renders as long as its dependencies have not changed.

`useCallback` lets you cache a function definition.

Comment: Hm but in his case there are no deps, the perf benefit is not creating a JSX function each time to render against item data (which changes every call so can't be memoized). `useMemo` can't even take arguments as you're not supposed to return a function to be called, you're supposed to return a result. `useCallback` is the proper thing to use imo, your example doesn't even work in the case of a callback which accepts `item`.

Comment: @Dominic In his question he was asking about `renderFooter` which he uses like this: `ListFooterComponent={renderFooter()}` in this case it doesn't make sense to use `useCallback` for `renderFooter`, because he is calling it anyway. I think my answer was written with a slightly different focus (because OP doesn't ask about " how to skip an expensive re-render of a child using `useMemo`") but still `useMemo` is more suitable for `renderFooter` IMHO.

Comment: Ah fair, missed he was talking about renderFooter

Answer (score 0):

"Should" is a matter of opinion, but you certainly *can*. React elements are fully reusable. It's not likely to make any real difference to your component, though, since creating the elements is fast and `renderFooter` is just used immediately in a component that's already running (unlike `keyExtractor` and `renderItem`, which you're passing to `FlatList`, so you want to make them stable where possible so `FlatList` can optimize its re-rendering). But you certainly can do that.

Answer (score 0):

`useMemo` is perfectly sensible here as it memoizes the result (the JSX). As you say, `useCallback` memoizes the *function* not the result.